# Natural transformations of the identity functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, natural-transformations

For a category $\mathbb{C},$ with identity functor $\mathbb{C} \overset{1_\mathbb{C}}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{C},$ I have recently found that natural transformations $1_\mathbb{C} \overset{\alpha}{\rightarrow} 1_\mathbb{C}$ can be very interesting. Mainly I am wondering if such natural transformations have been studied before. Do they have a name ? Can anybody recommend literature or important results about them to look at?

More concretely, I am also wondering what kinds of categories $\mathbb{C}$ have natural isomorphisms $1_\mathbb{C} \overset{\alpha}{\rightarrow} 1_\mathbb{C}$ other than the identity of $1_\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: I believe I've seen this described as the "centre" of the category. (On the basis that when you treat a group as a 1-object category, natural transformations of the identity functor correspond to group elements that commute with all other group elements.)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any literature referring to this ?

Comment: Not off-hand, sorry.

Comment: See citations and references on https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/center#OfCategories .